# Can't push to gitlab server from shell

Tags: gitlab

I have GitLab Server installed locally and i can pull and push from eclipse using EGIT plugin but i can't push from shell.
i'm getting an error message saying i don't have permission when i'm using the HTTP URL and bad password when i'm using SSH URL(the password i'm using is  100% good and working from the web client or eclipse)
any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is it reachable in the browser? Possibly check your firewall settings for port port 80 on HTTP or 443 HTTPS and try to change them to be more leniant.

Comment: Yes, it's reachable from browser and from eclipse and i can execute all the  git commands (commit,push,pull...). but from the GIT Client and shell i cant push, pull or fetch.